# Passing data back and forth between 2 child views controllers

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

wanted to see if somebody can provide some suggestions/pointers on how to address this issue I am currently facing for an **iPad** app. Here is a link to the graphic that I am describing below
http://www.yogile.com/dsruyzk7/41m/share/?vt=QANtu4j

Basically I have a parentViewController which contains 2 child view controllers. Child 1 has a UITableView and 
Child 2 has a custom UIView. I am able to load the info from UITableview on Child 1 to the custom UIView on Child 2 from didSelectRowAtIndexPath. After the data is 
displayed on Child 2 I do some processing. After the processing is complete, I need to update the UITableView on Child 1 so that the new/updated data 
gets displayed on the UITableView. I tried creating a delegate on Child 1 but wasn't working maybe I set something wrong. So any help suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

## .h on Child 2 ViewController

```
@class Child2ViewController;

@protocol child2Delegate <NSObject>
- (void)refreshTable:(Child2ViewController*)controller passedDict:(NSDictionary *)dict;

@interface Child2ViewController:UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    UITableView *myTableView;
    id<child2Delegate> delegate;
    Child1ViewController *child1VC;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<child2Delegate> delegate;
…
…

@end
```

## .m on Child 2 ViewController

```
@synthesize delegate;
…
..
..
#after all the processing is done we are ready to refresh the view
#updatedDictForTableView is basically a NSDictionary and has the updated data needed
#for the UITableview on child1VC.

-(void)processData {
    child1VC.delegate = self
    NSLog(@"Dump the updated Data : %@", updatedDictForTableView);
    [delegate refreshTable:self passedDict:updatedDictForTableView;
}
```

## .h in Child1 ViewController

```
@interface Child1ViewController : UIViewController <child2Delegate> {
    ….
    ….
    ..
}
```

## .m in Child1 ViewController

```
- (void)refreshTable:(Child2ViewController*)controller passedDict:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    NSLog(@"dump dict %@", dict);
    [myTableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Did you call the delegate?  Post some code so we can see more clearly what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. just added some code on how I am setting up the delegate and calling them. Again thanks for taking the time in looking at this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that without delegate, use NSNotificationcenter to send a notification with your values in the nsdictionary: exple :

```
  // in child1 ( in viewDiDLoad function )
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(FunctionToReloadData:) name:@"ProcessDone" object:nil];

  // remove the listnerin child1 ( in viDidUnload )
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"ProcessDone"];

 //in child2 ( in the end of your processData function )
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ProcessDone" object:nil userInfo:updatedDictForTableView ];


 //in child1
 -(void) FunctionToReloadData:(NSNotification *)notification
 {
    // get the sended dictionary
    NSDictionary *tmpDic = [notification userInfo];
     .
     .
     [tableView reloadData];

 }
```

Comment: Thank you Malek for your help. This worked. One other issue related to this scenario is when the parent view is loaded I need to default the Child 2 details with the data from the first row of Child 1 tableview. I followed the similar approach…creating the postNotification (with a different name) in Child 1 within viewDidLoad, creating the observer in the Child 2 viewDidLoad. When I run, I see in the debugger calling the addObserver method on child 2, but the method within the observer is never called. Any ideas?
here's my code...

Comment: '#child 1 viewDidLoad
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"loadInitialDetails"                                                           object:nil userInfo:tmpDict];
<br/>
 #child 2 viewDidLoad
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadDetails:) name:@"loadInitialDetails"  object:nil];
 -(void) loadDetails:(NSNotification *)notification {
      debugLog(@"Received Notification...%@", [notification userInfo]);
  [self anotherMethodToLoadDetailsBasedOnuserInfo];
 }'

Comment: If i understand the scenario and just to be sure, have you instantiate child1 and child2 before adding the observer ?

Comment: yes, both the child VCs have been instantiated by the parent and the tableview on child 1 is displayed with data on viewDidLoad.

Comment: You can pass the data you to child2 with a custum init function : in child2 : -(id) initwithDetails:(NSDictionary*) dic { if (self = [ super init ] ) {myInfoDictionary = [[ nsdictionary alloc]iniwithdictionary:dic] return self;}  i write this on my phone so verify the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding a parent table view property to the child class (here it would be considered as the detail view, or DetailViewController)

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
...
UITableView *parentTableView;
...
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView* parentTableView;
```

Then you set that property somewhere in your child 1 before showing something on child 2, maybe like in viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.detailViewController.parentTableView = self.tableView;
}
```

Then you're all set to reload the child 1 tableview inside the child 2 table view...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried what was mentioned here..basically on Child 2 I created parentTableView property and synthesized it. Then on Child 1, I added self.myViewController.parentTable = self.tableView in viewWillAppear. On Child 2, I have [parentTableView reloadData] after some processing and have setup some breakpoints on my tableview in Child 1 hoping to see the table getting refreshed..Unfortunately, I do not see the tableview refreshing/reloading the data...any ideas?

Comment: When you reach the breakpoint to [parentTableView reloadData], did you verify that you have a valid pointer (should not be nil)?

Comment: Just double checked my app that is using this method and it works well. I would check around the data being updated and saved in the child 2 (detail view). If you update something and save, check in the debugger if your reloadData is being called and also put a breakpoint in the child 1 view controller in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Is it being called?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time in reviewing this issue. Yeah my [parentTableView reloadData] does not get executed at all. So I do not see the cellForRowAtIndexPath being called on child1. As I mentioned earlier, I do have a valid pointer to the parentTableView.